# Android, Is it possible to copy audio or video to clipboard programically

Tags: android, audio, video, copy-paste, clipboardmanager

I am developing simple app to copy text/image/audio/video to clipboard in Android.

I can copy text and image to clipboard but is it possible copy audio or video like iOS?

Here is the sample of copy image to clipboard.

```
ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "Image/jpg");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filename.getAbsolutePath());
ContentResolver theContent = getContentResolver();
Uri imageUri = theContent.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
ClipData theClip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "Image", imageUri);
mClipboard.setPrimaryClip(theClip);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can copy/paste pretty much anything, try reading [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html) guide for insight.